# How to enable event sounds on Xubuntu?

Tags: sound, xubuntu

I was able to do this before, but I cannot for the life of me remember how. Its not just a simple as opening up a sound settings manager and selecting system sounds (unless there is a package I can install? let me know), it had to do with running a few commands in terminal. If anyone knows anything, please let me know.

INFO: Xubuntu 19.04
      Fresh install

Comment: It shows that they are enabled. What I mean is, how to enable a different event sounds scheme. I know how to download them, and where to put them ( `usr/share/sounds`), but theres a way to actually enable all of the different sounds themselves, like for right clicks, clicking the app drawer button, opening and closing windows, and maximizing and minimizing them etc

Comment: I've started to trace back in my browsing history, looking for the exact way that I did it previously. I'll find it and then post my solution.

Comment: yes, thats what I am trying to do. But in xubuntu, there is no gui way to change these sounds, or even enable them in the first place. At least not in Xubuntu

Comment: This is the one that I've used before: https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1149504/
this is the exact one that i was using before I did a fresh install. There was a way to do this, I just cant remember. Im trying to find what i did through my browser history lol

Comment: for sure. I'll be here

Comment: ok so i found what it is that i did, now i just have to figure out HOW i did it. I guess i added `GTK_MODULES="$GTK_MODULES:canberra-gtk-module"
export GTK_MODULES` to the end of `~/.profile`

Comment: hmm, thats weird. Oh wait, you have to follow the link thats there, it sends you to the archived version. One sec, ill grab the final one

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/mjtwkgvjmmn/Fresh+and+Clean.tar.gz

Comment: So I got ONE sound to work, the sound for when i click the logout button lol. But this is nowhere near what I had. The method I used before enabled sounds for all sorts of things... and it was just a few commands, like the one that I mentioned above

Comment: oooofffffff I figured it out. I'll post my solution in an edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the way to do this, I forgot that there is documentation on this somewhere on the Ubuntu forums. I figured I'd post it here for anyone looking to do this :) (this is for the sound theme "smooth", but it is easily adapted for almost any sound theme you want to install). I have also made a few relative changes, to make this more readable:

1. Install some required packages:
   `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-canberra sox`
2. Download the sound theme
3. Extract the file:
   tar xzvf foo.tar.gz
4. Copy the extracted content ("foo" folder) to your sounds directory:
   `/.local/share/sounds`
   (create the "sounds" directory if it does not exist yet)
5. Enable sound events and feedback sounds.

In example in Mate go to Control Center --> Sounds and enable them there; in Xfce it is done by entering in the terminal:
`xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/EnableEventSounds -s true`
`xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/EnableInputFeedbackSounds -s true`

6. Set "foo" as the default sound theme

In example in Mate go to `Control Center --> Sounds` and set it there; in Xfce it is done by entering in the terminal:
`xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/SoundThemeName -s "foo"`

7. Setup the necessary environment variable. Add to the end of `~/.profile:`
   Code:

`GTK_MODULES="$GTK_MODULES:canberra-gtk-module"
export GTK_MODULES`

That should be it. Perhaps a logout is needed before it starts working.

--//--

8. For a startup sound, create a new autostart application (`Settings Manager` or `Control Center` >> Session and startup >> Application autostart) with the following parameters:
   `- Name = Login Sound`
   `- Command = canberra-gtk-play -f ~/.local/share/sounds/foo/stereo/desktop-login.oga`
9. For logout sound, you need override `xfce4-session`. To do so, with root privliges, create the file `/usr/local/bin/xfce4-session` with the following content..

Content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# run the real xfce4-session executable
/usr/bin/xfce4-session

# on exit, run my stuff
canberra-gtk-play -f ~/.local/share/sounds/foo/stereo/desktop-logout.oga
```

And make this file executable:
`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xfce4-session`

Comment: lol thank you! It was so frustrating at first, but thank you for helping me!

Comment: hey, also, i wanted to give yo a link to a WAYYY better sound theme for Xubuntu: https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1187979/
Thats the one I'm using now. I messed up earlier when I referenced that "fresh and clean" one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it helped to go to:
Start menu - All Settings - Appearance (VERY unintuitive) - Settings tab - Event sounds - Enable event sounds.

After enabling I can hear a sound when new e-mail arrives. Though, I don't know how to change sound theme or anything, unless it is program/notification specific sound which I can change in the program (for example in Thunderbird).

Comment: Nice! My question and answer were geared more towards the various system UI sounds, like one that gets made when you click the programs menu, or click the minimize or maximize window button, or other various ones. If you're into having these sounds, you should really check them out! the opendesktop website has some pretty neat sound themes, that you can apply with my answer above. Give your desktop a modern and responsive feel to it!